# How can I configure the legend with a specific height in highstock?

Tags: jquery, padding, highcharts, legend

I need the legend with 450px height all the time without matter how many series in the chart,I use

```
                $('.highcharts-legend rect').attr('height','475');
```

but that is not effective, I need something like padding option in legend but only padding Bottom, how can I do that, thanks

This example is ok http://jsfiddle.net/DZLdt/ I only want to do something like 
                     height: 475 in legend configurations

Comment: Please give some HTML for this. Or do you have Fiddle for it?

Answer (score 2):

Highcharts provides a maxLimit to the legendHeight.

`legend: {
    maxHeight: 475
}`

But if the count of items in it is lesser the legend shrinks but the legend wont go beyond the maxHeight. if at all the items are more the navigator starts for the legend.

API ref: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#legend.maxHeight

I hope this will be of some use for you

Answer (score 0):

There is no height setting properties in the documentation I see. You can use the same code you have used in the question to set the height of the `rect`, but I saw your svg is going beyond the bounds. So you will need to manually set the height attribute of the svg being drawn also with the script below to let the increased height of the legend to be acommodated inside the svg.

```
$('.highcharts-container svg').height(heightToIncludeTheIncrease);
```

I just tried with the developer tools to check if it works. So in conslusion, you will need to increase the containers to acommodate the increased height, starting from the parents of the `rect`.